# How do I make half the sentence <h2>?

Tags: html

```html
<h1 style="color: white;">We are here to <span style="color: #fdd412;">Rock</span> the <span style="color: #fdd412;">modern world</span></h1>
```

So, I made some words another color, but how do I make this sentence from the "The" part `<h2>`? So "We are here to rock" in `<h1>` and "the modern world" in `<h2>`?

Comment: Just mark it up that way? .. `<h1> [...] Rock</span></h1><h2>the <span style [...] </h2>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use one `h#` in another `h#` at all. You can, however, achieve this by adding `display: inline-block` to both tags.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2, h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color: white;">We are here to&nbsp;<h2><span style="color: #fdd412;">Rock</span> the <span style="color: #fdd412;">modern world</span></h2></h1>
```

The preferred way would be to instead add extra classes and use those.

```css
body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

h1,
.h1-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h2,
.h2-subtitle {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.h1-title,
.h2-subtitle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1-title">We are here to
  <div class="h2-subtitle"><span style="color: #fdd412;">Rock</span> the <span style="color: #fdd412;">modern world</span></div>
</div>
```

But I think it would be tidier to just do this:

```css
body {
  background-color: olive;
}

h1.title {
  color: white;
}

h1.title,
h2.subtitle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">We are here to</h1>
<h2 class="subtitle"><span style="color: #fdd412;">Rock</span> the <span style="color: #fdd412;">modern world</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must need a CSS-File. This should look like this:

**CSS:**

```
h1, h2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}​
```

And the **HTML** should look like this: (i don't know if i understand the question correctly which part shoud be h1 and which h2)

```
<h1 style="color: blue;">We are here to<span style="color: #fdd412;"> Rock</span></h1>
<h2>the <span style="color: #fdd412;">modern world</span></h2>
```

[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruTR2.png)